# MaxCharLimit on the TextInput according to it's width

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

I am using Flex 4.5 and I want to set the maximum characters limit according to the textinput width means if user enter more character then the textinput width it should not accept those extra characters.

Comment: You're going to have to do some width calculations based on the font.  There is not an easy "character" limit to enforce because most fonts do not have all characters the same width.  If you Google "Flex measureText" some information comes up.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, i have no flex in front of me right now.
You should know, how many space e.g. 20 characters needed and set this value to your textinput.width.

Check out the widthInChars-property for the spark Textinput. Maybe you can work with a litte offset. When it works, you just have to synchronize this value with maxChars.
Let me know, if that work.
Frank