# Update label text according to label width and string length dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have a label a textInput and a button like below

```
<s:TextInput id="inputTxt"/>
<s:Label id="lbl" height="50" width="100" backgroundColor="blue"/>
<s:Button id="btn" label="Marquee" height="40" width="80" click="btn_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

and my function updates the `lbl.text` on btn click and its working.
But i need to update the label text dynamically and my function looks like this

```
protected function btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  str = inputTxt.text;
  strLen = str.length;
  lbl.text = updateLabel(inputTxt.text);
}


private function updateLabel(str:String):String
{
  var displayFact:int;// code should be updated here

  if(strLen > 14)
      displayFact = 12;
  else
      displayFact = strLen;

  return new String(str).substr(0,displayFact);
}
```

can you suggest how can i calculate `displayFact` so that according to `lbl.width` and `str.length` it will changes and the `str` should fit the width of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way because the width of a char is not constant and the font is not the same.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309255/maxcharlimit-on-the-textinput-according-to-its-width) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628368/length-of-a-string-in-pixels)

Instead if what you are trying to achieve is just hide the exceeding text you can truncate using

```
<s:Label id="lbl" height="50" width="100" maxDisplayedLines=1 backgroundColor="blue"/>
```

Comment: if i use maxDisplayLines=1 then if the string is big it shows like "Good Morn...."  so insted i use updateLabel(). any way thank you for the links